# How to add individual elements of list into another list in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For example i have the below list

```
list1 = [] 
list2 = ['cat', 'tiger']
```

I wanted to add only the individual elements in the list2 into list1.
For eg,

```
list1.append(['wolf', list2])
```

And wanted the output like,

```
[[wolf, cat, tiger]]
```

But instead I get like,

```
[['wolf', ['cat', 'tiger']]]
```

I don't want list2 as such getting appended with the brackets, rather only the elements from the list2. Am i missing something ? Please add your comments. This is just an example from a bigger problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use unpacking

```
>>> list1.append(['wolf', *list2])

[['wolf', 'cat', 'tiger']]
```

In case `python2`

```
>>> list1.append(['wolf'] + list2)
```

Comment: It says   File "txtwrp.py", line 52
    list1.append(['wolf', *list2])
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Desperado your older python version probably has no unpacking yet. Try edited

Comment: So then it's not a duplicate. It's tagged python 2.7

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 fair enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list1=[["wolf"]+list2]
```